# #region sections not being recognised in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2019

Running Visual Studio Professional 2019 v16.11.16.

My .NET solution has several C# and VB.NET modules with `#region\#endregion` and `#Region\#End Region` sections. The existing regions in the VB modules have a "+" or "-" in the left margin and can be collapsed or expanded as normal.

But new and existing regions are not being recognised in the .cs files:

```
#region Test region
// Nothing appears in the margin at any time and block cannot be collapsed
#endregion
```

Confusingly, in some .cs files existing regions *are* recognised! But in no .cs file are new `#region` sections being recognised.

Although working in .vb files, if there is any syntax error anywhere in the `#Region\#End Region` block, the region stops being recognised and the icon disappears.

New classes, methods, `try/catch`, `if` statements, etc. in .cs files *are* being recognised as code blocks and can be collapsed/expanded as normal.

What setting(s) affect `#region` identification? Could something be broken in a recent VS 2019 update?

Comment: *Could something be broken in a recent VS 2019 update?* The generic answer to that specific question is: Yes! ;-)

Comment: @AlainD there are no compilation errors, right?

Comment: @viveknuna: That's correct - the `#region` sections produce no build errors. As mentioned, some (old) regions still work in .cs files which suggests a stale cache somewhere (or VS2019 is not refreshing that cache for some reason).

Comment: I am not sure, but you could try cleaning, rebuilding, restarting VS, try setting the VS to default, repairing VS, raising bug @AlainD and you are free not to take my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearing the cache and the following folders did not help:

- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VSCommon

A clue was the difference between C# and VB. So after hunting through settings specific for C# I finally found the setting:

`Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Outlining > Show outlining for comments and preprocessor regions`

Turning that on resolved the problem. Not sure when or why that was turned off. Hope this helps someone else.